# Disable C# 6.0 Support in ReSharper

Tags: c#, resharper

While using ReSharper, it suggested "Enable C# 6.0 support for this project". I foolishly clicked on it, and now as advertised it's giving me suggestions for C# 6.0 - which then give me errors as I am not using C# 6.0 in this project.

How can I disable C# 6.0 support, returning it to how it was before? (Preferably without having to individually ignore specific suggestions)

Comment: This just happened to me but I don't recall seeing that suggestion. I was creating a new class in my project, implementing an interface and it was suggesting c# 6 stuff. I was so confused....

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Click the project node in the Solution Explorer. Then look in the Property Grid (F4). You'll see a property named "C# Language Level". Set that to "Default" or your desired language level.

[image]

Comment: This is not available in VS2015 Preview, any alternatives?

Comment: It is available under Project => Properties => Build => Advanced.

Comment: It is available in 2015 RC, on projects, not on the solution.

Comment: Is there perhaps a better solution when having to do this with a lot of projects? Something more globally?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester just multi select all projects to set Language Level once for the whole solution. Each project wil get it's own .DotSettings file

Comment: FYI - Selecting "Default" in VS2015 RTM will still leave C# 6.0 enabled (that's apparently the default in VS2015) -- you need to explicitly select C# 5.0 if that's what you want.

Comment: @IlyaSuzdalnitski Unfortunly, it doesn't work. For example C# suggests C# 6.0 syntax, I accept changes and then VS stays "hey, it's C# 6.0 syntax while you set C# 5.0 for a project, I won't compile it)! So R# uses its own settings and do not respect VS's.

Comment: The other answer is better because it works solution-wide

Comment: @disklosr Not always, sometimes you can have different projects at different language levels in the same solution

Comment: @Jake this answer too doesn't always work, sometimes you've got several projects under one solution and it's a pain to change the settings for each individual one.

Answer (score 59):

TO disable it at once across the solution rather than per project level, please add below in `.sln.DotSettings`

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/CSharpLanguageProject/LanguageLevel/@EntryValue">CSharp50</s:String>
```

it would disable resharper 6.0 features/give you error

**EDIT**

as per comments, in case you dont have the `sln.DotSettings` file at all, then you need to create one with below contents

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"> 
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/CSharpLanguageProject/LanguageLevel/@EntryValue">‌​CSharp50</s:String>
</wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, it solves the problem at solution level, i.e. without the need to set per csproj property

Comment: Here is the entire content of sln .DotSettings file, in case you need to recreate it like i did. `<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
 <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/CSharpLanguageProject/LanguageLevel/@EntryValue">CSharp50</s:String></wpf:ResourceDictionary>`

Comment: @JesonMartajaya updated answer to include your comments

Comment: This works for me. Heads-up though: that first XML snippet has an unmatched </wpf:ResourceDictionary> tag at the end.

Comment: Well now this isn't working for me at all. Not sure why, but ReSharper will just not honor that setting for some reason, and keeps suggesting changes that won't work in C# 5.0.

Comment: Updated: I was tearing my hair out trying to figure out why this wasn't working. Turns out I had changed the language setting in the project properties, which creates a .csproj.DotSettings file. When I changed the setting back to "Default" from "CSharp50," the "Default" in the project-specific settings was overriding the solution-wide "CSharp50" setting. Removing the .csproj.DotSettings file and re-opening the solution fixed it.

Comment: Note that this workaround does require VS2015. It will not work in VS2013.

Comment: @AnneTheAgile  Does vs2013 support c# 6?

Comment: @entre , I had thought, from what I read, that one is able to add c# 6 support to vs2013, since older dotnets can be upgraded/ modified. But alas it does not seem to go as far as vs2013 usage, unless there is some trick I didn't do.

Comment: You can create DotSettings file (team or user) with GUI: ReSharper -> Manage Options... Copy Settings To

Comment: Note that you need to reopen your project/solution for VS2015 to pick up your changes. At least I had to...