# How do I disable C# 6 Support in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-5.0, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

### Background

We have a project that we're developing in VS 2015 with C#6 enabled that occasionally needs to be opened by developers using VS 2013 without C#6.

We have no intention to use C# 6 within this particular solution (as much as I'd like to).

### Problem

Visual Studio and ReSharper suggest helpful C# 6 language constructs that render the solution inoperable in earlier versions of Visual Studio without C#6 support.

I've [disabled the ReSharper C#6 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621458/resharper-disable-c-sharp-6-0-support) but I can't seem to disable / limit C# features across the whole solution.

### Question

How do I limit C# to C#5 capabilities within a solution or within Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Build tab, Advanced button, Language version setting.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks! This is exactly it. I'll write it up in answer form but if you post the answer here, I'll be sure to mark yours as the correct one.

Comment: Exactly my problem! except our solution is in 2013, but I want to continue  using VS2015 instead.

Comment: @entre there's not necessarily a need; you can always just not *use* the C#6 features. Visual studio and resharper helpfully suggest refactorings that utilize these features, though. As long as your build machine supports C#6, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I dont want to use c#6... but I am still getting those suggestions.. i removed them for resharper.. but asking for visual studio... i guess visual studio wont provide intellisense suggesting c#6 because my .net framework is 4.5

Comment: Entire -- if you follow the directions in the answer, you'll be setting it for visual studio. You change the language from "default" to 5. It's in each project's properties

Comment: @SeanKilleen Our checkin build machine does not so we encountered the issue. Also some devs using VS2013 due to perf issues and bugs in VS2015 (regressions introduced by Roslyn) so I'm looking to disable C# 6.0 on a few solutions if possible.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can set the language feature for each project separately by going to `Properties => Build tab => Advanced button => Language Version` and set your preferred version.

You should realize that it will still use the new "C# 6.0" .Net Compiler Platform (codenamed Roslyn). However, that compiler will *imitate* the behavior of older compilers and will limit you to features only available on that specific language version.

---

I don't think that there's a solution-wide setting available.

Comment: Do you know if there is an equivalent setting for VB.NET?

Comment: I got my answer earlier today. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454902/restrict-new-language-features-of-visual-basic-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: After changes in Project properties my Studio just marks C# 6.0 code in editor. But doesn't treat it as error (builds successfully).

Comment: If you have many projects, I recommend editing the csproj directly. Add the following inside the first `PropertyGroup` element: `<LangVersion>5</LangVersion>`

Comment: Works exactly the same way to disable C#7 support in VS2017 - simply use `<LangVersion>6</LangVersion>` instead.

Answer (score 49):

add below in `.sln.DotSettings` should disable it on solution level

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/CSharpLanguageProject/LanguageLevel/@EntryValue">CSharp50</s:String>
```

---

Or if you don't have a `.sln.DotSettings` file:

1. If your solution file is called Apple.sln, create a file beside it called Apple.sln.DotSettings.
2. Give it the following contents:

   ```
   <wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
       <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/CSharpLanguageProject/LanguageLevel/@EntryValue">CSharp50</s:String>
   </wpf:ResourceDictionary>
   ```
3. Close and reopen the solution, Resharper should only warn you about C#5 things.
4. Don't forget to remove this when you eventually start using C#6 features! :)

Comment: This should be marked as the answer as it applies to all projects within a solution and is a file can be checked in.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse actually this answer is only relevant to Resharper which OP already disabled, so it doesn't even answer the question.

Comment: I also agree that, this should be marked as answer. OP has asked about solution wide settings, which ONLY this answer provides.

Comment: Well, anyhow this does not prevent Visual Studio to show Microsoft's own recommendations for code improvements (it was the actual question to prevent those). This answer does work for ReSharper, not for Visual Studio (Not all of us are using ReSharper).

Answer (score 11):

This [tool](https://github.com/khellang/LangVersionFixer) I wrote might help you if you have many projects that you need to set `LangVersion` for.

Answer (score 10):

You can set the language feature for all the `solutions/csproj` with the `MSBuildUserExtensionsPath`.

Search the value of the `$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)`, it should be something like `C:\Users\$(User)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild`

Then edit the file `Force.LangVersion.ImportBefore.props` in the folder `$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)\14.0\Imports\Microsoft.Common.Props\ImportBefore` with :

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>5</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 9):

Steps have already been written above, just adding a screenshot further of my VS2015:

Properties of project >> Build >> Advanced >> Language version

[image]

I set that to C# 5.0.

Answer (score 8):

Right click on Project in Project Explorer and select Properties.

When the Properties tab opens select Build and the click the Advance button in bottom right.

There is drop-down box called Language Version. Change the select to "C# 5.0"