# Turn off support for C# 6 language features in ReSharper

Tags: c#, resharper

I am using VS 2015 + ReSharper. However my team mates are still using VS 2013/2012 and they don't have the new C# 6 goodness. The problem is that some refactorings of ReSharper (like argument null checks) use the new features (like `nameof` operator). The question is how to turn that off and switch back to old style because I don't want to push code that my team mates can't compile yet.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461640/how-do-i-disable-c-sharp-6-support-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: As an aside, this is why a team should use the same development tools (and tool versions). Given that VS installations can live side by side, I would advise keeping VS2012/2013 installed for working on these projects.

Comment: I am contractor and the benefits of using VS2015 for the specific tasks that I am assigned are greater than the problems it may cause.