# How can you stop Resharper from suggesting NET 4.6 features?

Tags: resharper

How can you stop Resharper from suggesting NET 4.6 features?

In this case it's suggesting adding ...

```
using static System.String;
```

and changing `String.Format` to just `Format`, `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`to `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, etc.

I'm aware of adding ...

```
// ReSharper disable BuiltInTypeReferenceStyle
```

but I have to do this for all files *(and that's assuming I remember and don't just let Resharper make the change)*

How do you make sure it only suggests up to NET 4.5 features? *(as that is what's deployed on our servers)*

Comment: See ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621458/resharper-disable-c-sharp-6-0-support/27628609#27628609

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of them are in fact C# 6 language or compiler features.

Set project language level back to C# 5 or lower and then you will not see many of them.

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/ReSharper_by_Language__CSharp.html

Comment: [How to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27628609/1698557), in case (like me) you didn't realize this was an option.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk Google returns this article as top result with such keywords.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk Excellent ... I'm indeed like you and I didn't realise it was an option