# Tell resharper to generate ToString in C# using string.Format?

Tags: c#, resharper

Currently resharper is generating ToString in C# using the string interpolation (i.e. `$"Member: {Member}"`).

Is it possible to modify it so it will use `string.Format` instead (i.e. `string.Format("Member: {0}",Member))`

Comment: String interpolation is a feature of C# 6. Are you looking to disable C# 6 support in your project? [That question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621458/disable-c-sharp-6-0-support-in-resharper) has been addressed before.

Comment: Maybe this could help: ReSharper -> Manage Options -> Code Edition -> C# -> Context Actions -> 

Disable "Convert to regular string interpolation"
Enable  "Convert to string.Format"

Comment: I am just looking to generate ToString using string.Format, I don't want to completely disable C# 6

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper > Options > Code Inspection + Inspection Severity > C# > "Language Usage Opportunities" > "Use string interpolation expression". Change this to "Do not show".

Comment: It doesn't help - it just prevents resharper from showing warnings on string.Format, but it still generates ToString using string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over the same problem in Resharper 2016.1

For me it helped to position the caret over the `+` operator in a string concatenation and hit `Alt+Enter`. It then lists an option to refactor to string.Format. Positioning the caret over the string does not work. The option will not be available in that case.

This must be a recent change because I use that refactoring often for localization reasons.

Answer (score -1):

It might be worth checking out Fody.ToString project, it can automatically create an overload of your ToString method after build using IL Weaving:

Your Code:

```
[ToString]
class TestClass
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }

    public double Bar { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDuringToString]
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

Gets converted to:

```
class TestClass
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }

    public double Bar { get; set; }

    public string Baz { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
            "{{T: TestClass, Foo: {0}, Bar: {1}}}",
            this.Foo,
            this.Bar);
    }
}
```

Check it out, right time saver - https://github.com/Fody/ToString